# Как в functions.php подключать php файлы(WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Стили в Wp подключаются так: wp_enqueue_style

Код javascript так: wp_enqueue_script

А как подключить библиотеку php кода?

Есть ДОМ-Парсер **simple_html_dom.php** как его подключить в **functions.php**

Answer (score 1):

Этот парсер представляет из себя один файл. Скачайте его, поместите, скажем, в корневую папку дочерней темы и используйте обычный require:

```
require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . 'simple_html_dom.php';
```